# Python script simulating compose key

Tags: python, paste

I would like to make a Python script for Linux that brings up a prompt, allows the user to enter some keystrokes, and then prints a special character into whatever GUI-based program/widget happens to have the focus after my Python script exits (which takes the focus after the prompt goes away). Note that 'whatever program I happen to be using' is not particularly a program I made myself.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I know how to make a prompt, do keybindings and all that. I know how to use both xclip and xsel to copy stuff to the clipboard and I imagine paste, too (though I haven't had the need to paste with them, before). Is there a way to use them or something else to paste into the program that has the focus after my program (as opposed to merely pasting into my program)?

Basically, I'm trying to simulate the compose key with a Python program because the compose key doesn't always work, anymore, on Xubuntu 14.04 for some reason (just sometimes, and temporarily). It worked fine in previous versions all the time. If I had a Python program that could do this, then I wouldn't have to worry about whether the compose key would work on any future Xubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer before I was done asking.

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Tab' 'keyup Alt_L' 'keydown Control_L' 'usleep 200000' 'key v' 'keyup Control_L'
```

You can surmise the rest. I just need to have Python execute the xte command above after I enter the keystrokes.

Comment: If you came here looking for a Windows solution, Automa could work even more easily, I believe, but I haven't tried it: http://www.getautoma.com/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something here that might be helpful for this:

https://github.com/gvb1234/simulate-compose-key

it intercepts the Multi_Key if the focus is in a particular app, and does some fancy things with the next few keys, if they form a valid compose sequence.

This could be easily modified to call xdotool (or directly from python) to send the proper utf8 character to the window in focus.